# How do I use hover in 2-3rd neted

Tags: css, sass

I have this architecture:

```
.about {
display: flex;
&__card {
transition: all .5s;
&--img {
filter: grayscale(1);
}
&:hover {
flex-grow: 2;
&--img {
filter: grayscale(0);
}
}
}
}
```

The last part of code is not working:

```
&--img {
filter: grayscale(0)
}
```

That only works if I use simple CSS:

```
&:hover {
flex-grow: 2;
.about__card--img {
filter: grayscale(0);
}
}
```

Comment: `:hover { &--img { ... } }` would be compiled to: `:hover--img { ... }` which is not a valid selector. Please post your HTML markup that you try to apply the CSS too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hover effect doesn't work as expected because the &--img selector fragment should be nested within &__card directly.

the corrected code is:

```
.about {
  display: flex;

  &__card {
    transition: all .5s;

    &--img {
      filter: grayscale(1);
    }

    &:hover {
      flex-grow: 2;
      .about__card--img {
        filter: grayscale(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `&--img` is not a class! it's a selector fragment added to the parent selector (fragment).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! You're correct. In Sass, &--img is selector fragment, not a separate class. Appreciate your input!